# Applying class on form submission on the div which wraps the input field which is invalid

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to Angularjs.I'm doing form validation and I want to apply a class on the div which contains a textbox with invalid state.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="input-group" ng-class="{invalidField:submitted && $scope.signupForm.fname.$Invalid }">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        </span>
        <input id="txtFirstName" ng-class="{submitted: submitted}" ng-model="user.FirstName" class="form-control" autofocus="" name="fname" type="text" required>
    </div>
    <span ng-show="submitted && signupForm.fname.$error.required">FirstName is required.</span>
</div>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg" ng-click="SignUpUser()" value="Sign Up" />
```

On the submission of form I set submitted = true.If submission is true and the field is invalid I want to apply class invalidField on the div but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be that one of your expressions uses a nested object, but I'm not sure about that. Instead of multiple expressions, use a scope function to do the comparison:

```
<div class="input-group" ng-class="{'invalidField': checkValidity()}">

<script>
$scope.checkValidity = function() {
    var valid = $scope.submitted && $scope.signupForm.fname.$Invalid;

    return valid;
};
</script>
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m1quy8sz/3/)**

This demo shows that the function returns true by way of the orange background.

Comment: Thanks isherwood.It worked but can anyone please explain what was the exact problem.

Comment: If you want more or better answers, leave the question open (unaccept my answer). Very few people will find your followup question here in the comments.